# Add a permanent command on boot with centos 7

Tags: centos7, systemd, boot

I want, when my CentOS  7 server boots, to run

```bash
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

because I want to reuse open connections.

Systemd is allready installed, but my command is not a service, just a one time execution command at startup.

How can I run automatically this command at startup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add your command to

```
 /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

and it will run at startup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. THis method may works, but in the rc.local file, it is wrote :THIS FILE IS ADDED FOR COMPATIBILITY PURPOSES
#
# It is highly advisable to create own systemd services or udev rules
# to run scripts during boot instead of using this file. Do You know the method with systemd ?

Comment: It will work - See here for detailed explanation => https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-execute-scripts-commands-using-etc-rc-d-rc-local-in-centos-rhel-7/

Comment: It works !  I added the rights as followed in your link. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to make the changes persistent is to edit the file:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

After the change, type:

```
sysctl -p
```

This will load the changes into the current session. The fact that the settings are in /etc/sysctl.conf will ensure that they load on reboots.